# email templates images on gcloud storage are not visible from gmail

Tags: gmail, gcloud

I have a storage bucket in google cloud and the url for the image is something like this

https://storage.cloud.google.com/my-bucket-name/image-name.png

then I use this link inside an email tempalte like this:

```
<a
  href="https://www.my-url.com"
  target="_blank"
  ><img
    src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/my-bucket-name/image-name.png"
    width="171"
    height="41"
    alt="some text"
    style="display: block; border: 0;"
/></a>
```

And I'm send my emails using mailjet api, but when I recibe the email on my gmail I get the following as a src

```
https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/l_BzLY1sw86Ny3rRX4-7HxNe_rnkhWBS66tHaw7vzKOYYDswmLnHIt-EnTcZ7meI3d3n_tpAf6pXlRXepwGTVJg0oQg5mUdRtlTr2XJuoqPzhjSZvzeJb2z8Ldelk8fGpz4=s0-d-e1-ft#https://storage.cloud.google.com/my-bucket-name/image-name.png
```

But no image, only the alt text, if I try with hotmail, I can see the image on the web, but If I use the iphone email app, I have the same problem with gmail no image, no matter if I'm checking a gmail or hotmail account, also the same problem happen inside the gmail app no image.

I was checking the bucket configuration, but I don't see any other permission in order to allow gmail to show my image.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: hey @Jean, what permissions do your bucket has? also, using this kind of links for objects "https://storage.cloud.google.com/my-bucket-name/image-name.png" will need to authenticate. you should [always use](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data#accessing-public-data) "https://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]" for application use.

Comment: Thank you so much @MethkalKhalawi that was the problem

Comment: I posted an answer. Please, accept it for the community visibility and benifits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should always use "storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]" for application use.